How can i analyze the transient response of a circuit?
I have recently become interested in electronic circuit design and transient analysis of these circuits. Unfortunately, throughout my university life, we have only studied the analysis of RLC circuits as transient analysis and I have no idea about transient analysis of semiconductor circuit elements. For example, I have no idea how to do transient analysis of FETs, BJTs, IGBTs. I do not want to reach a result by copying and pasting circuits designed by other people and making changes on them.
I am aware that the circuit in the photo is not a complex circuit, but I want you to give me an idea about it. How is transient analysis of circuits containing electronic elements other than resistors, capacitors and inductors done? What are the steps to be considered while doing it? What is the analysis method that should be applied in complex circuits? (In the Electronics-1&2 course at university, I could only work with 3-layer transistors, so when I open and look at the datasheet of an integrated circuit, I have tons of question marks in my mind about where to start)
In addition to these questions, let's consider a circuit element such as a MOSFET. In the circuit models we used at university, we simply touched on the MOSFET structure, but we did not touch on the real-life model of a MOSFET. Where can I research and learn these?
(Note: English is not my native language, so I apologize in advance if I have any mistakes.)
Best regards.

(Note: The numbers shown in the picture are completely random. I did not copy the circuit from any source. I wanted to measure how the circuit would react if I made it this way. However, when I wanted to calculate the transient analysis myself with a pen and paper, I could not do it. )

R2 and C1 are in quadrature to each other. You do need to narrow your question, too. For example, are you looking for the transient behavior of the collector-to-ground with respect to a sudden change in V2? The BJT will have parasitics, Early (and Late) Effects, and otherwise incorporate the Shockley equation (requiring the use of product-log/LambertW to solve.) But with an operating point determined to start, you can use a linearized BJT model with added AC complexity and then attempt an answer.

@periblepsis Hello, I didn't have the chance to review the entire document you added, I didn't expect the device models that I will look at in time to be so diverse. Thank you for sharing such a nice reference source. The question I wanted to ask was how can I do Transient circuit analysis (I'm talking about my own calculations using paper and pencil) and where and how can I reach realistic models of circuit elements while doing these circuit analyses? The circuit in the photo was to observe the reaction of the capacitor to this process when I switched DC voltage using a BJT.

@periblepsis In other words, in the switched RC circuit example we saw at school, I actually wanted to use a switch from the transistor family instead of an ideal switch. I'll take a look at the Sockley equation and its purposes. Thank you for answering my question and sharing the reference document. Best regards.

When you want to study the transitory of an electrical network, first of all there must be a switch in the network that, with its closing, establishes the beginning of the transient. Generally, one operates on the Laplace transformed circuit. In the Laplace domain, the switch is omitted and an independent generator is connected directly to the transformed network whose voltage or current is the Laplace transform of the voltage in the time domain.

@capacitor_enthusiast If you were to provide more detail about exactly what you are shooting for (is it impulse-response, step-response, or sensitivity analysis) and where the input/output is taken then I might find a path to write something. Otherwise, I'm throwing mud at the wall to see what sticks. Your words do have meaning. But my mind sees an open delta of paths outward. So I'm stuck.

In the real world outside of university, transient responses are often not simulated except in evaluation phases of design. I do transient analysis almost every day at work using my oscilloscope and setting a trigger event. For example, if I plug in power, how will a particular FET or IC respond? From the captured transient event of me turning on power, I can look at any anomalies, i.e. overshoot, etc. It's really more of a practice that you'll learn once you graduate. Transient responses are behavior over a period of time and can be sometimes unpredictable.
That being said, technically, you could predict some transient behavior. For instance, if you don't have enough capacitors, you may see some oddities in your transmission lines. But there's a lot of factors outside of SPICE software that can cause strange behavior. When you develop a PCB, there can be a lot of unaccounted electromagnetic activity if you don't review how you've laid everything out. Datasheets and application notes for products can help prevent a lot of design errors looking at various behavioral charts listed but even sometimes those have mistakes and it can be a little difficult to predict if it will be compatible for rest of your design. The best you can do is follow what is said in the datasheet and application notes.
But you're right. University teaches you a lot about the ideal behavior of FETs, capacitors, etc. But I wouldn't worry too much about real behavior once you graduate. It's something you'll learn as you start working. No one is going to expect a new graduate to really know too much about that. As I said before, it comes with practice. I know there's an overwhelming curiosity of feeling unprepared for the real world because right now, you're doing a lot of math and theory and sometimes your lab classes don't feel like it's preparing you for the real world. Trust me, I felt the same way.
Even to this day, even seven years after graduating, I'm still learning new things about circuit behavior in the real world. I refer to my old textbooks constantly because there's moments where I forget about certain behaviors of components. But I have teammates at work who can back me up. Heck, I sit next to a couple of engineers with over 30 years of experience who argue about fundamental facts about transistors and microcontrollers all the time.
Don't fret about being an expert before you graduate. Focus on your academics. Once you start your first job after university, be prepared to absorb a lot of knowledge. You'll learn through experience.

first of all, thank you for sharing your experiences and making suggestions. I am currently in my 4th year and doing my last internship. I feel excited to graduate after my internship. After the theoretical background provided by the university and the tons of lab classes I attended, I was disappointed that most of the things I learned were simple and according to the ideal model. I guess I need to learn some things by experience and making mistakes. As you said, I will take a look at the datasheets and application notes.
Best regards :)

@capacitor_enthusiast You're welcome  When you start working, you'll be surprised how fast you'll learn. Things feel very slow during university so I understand the frustration. Best of luck during your final year of school.

To add to what @Colin said, most of the time transient effects are abstracted UNLESS the focus is the transient effect itself. A heavily researched transient effect of the MOSFET for instance, is the reduction of switching losses, which arise due to the capacitive nature of the MOSFET owing to its internal design (see Miller Effect). Another research area is improving the thermal behaviour of the MOSFET, in particular reducing the switching and conduction losses, which again arise due to transient effect(s) as well as the internal structure of the MOSFET. Another research area is improving the control of a MOSFET, which may involve, increasing its maximum possible switching frequency for example, again capped at least thermally by the switching losses.
As to where to "attain this knowledge" from, as @Colin mentions, you would attain it from research and/or industrial experience. I started off as an outsider in this field, since my major is in Informatics, however with time and research have learned a thing or two. To get an idea of what problems are being tackled in real-life, a good start would be to read publications by the manufacturers themselves. For instance this writeup by Infineon AG, talking about the challenges in building in an NTC-Sensor on a MOSFET Chip in an Inverter.
A highly comprehensive guide to challenges in modern day development of MOSFETs and Semiconductors in general can be found in the SEMIKRON Application Handbook.
I hope this helps you in some way. Happy Learning!

Hello, I will take a look at the review areas you shared about MOSFET. I tried to look through the documents you shared, not in detail, and I will continue to review them. I think that I will gain a good perspective in the future with these documents and the research I will do. I especially thank you for the document prepared by SEMIKRON, it is a great reference source for me.
Best regards.

No problem. In fact the one from SEMIKRON is informally considered as a "Bible" for modern power electronic applications (at least where I work at). Good luck!
